# How do you add a comment field to a approve/reject workflow

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, designer-workflow

I have a work list workflow that has approve and reject. i want the approver to give reasons as to why they are rejecting the request.
Is there a way to do this without editting codes?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Your tags indicate that you are using a SP Designer workflow. If that's the case, then yes -- you just need to add an initiation form parameter (in the designer ribbon, "variables" section.

Comment: Thank you Joe H. But this way you can only have predefined default Text. i want the approver to be able to comment real time.

Comment: I don't quite follow. You can add a single line of text, or multi line of text initiation parameter and the approver can add any comments they want, then, your workflow can write the contents of the parameter to, for instance, a "comments" column in your list item.